# Current in open circuit between series capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, voltage, capacitance

Suppose we charged two capacitors $C_1$ and $C_2$ independently in two independent circuits with no connections between them. We then take the capacitors out of their respective circuits and connect them in series, but without closing the circuit:

$--|C_1|---|C_2|--$

Since the negatively charged terminal of $C_1$ is now connected to a positively charged terminal of $C_2$, would there be any transient current flowing after the capacitors are connected?
If not, what happens to the charges?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I connect two charged capacitors side by side, what will be the voltage across them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33699/)

Answer (score 0):

The charges on the two "outer" plates have nowhere to go and hold the charges on their respective "inner" plates in position, ie not allowing them to move.
As far a the distribution of charges on the two capacitors is concerned it makes no difference as whether the two "inner" plates are connected or not connected.

Comment: I'd like to see this verified via measurements.